# Canonical isomorphism between a module and its dual (without going to its existence)

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, $1$, which is not $0$.

I am trying to see what is meaning of canonical isomorphism of an $R$-module $M$ and its dual $M^*={\rm Hom}_R(M,R)$, without worrying whether it exists or not.

**How it was defined:** Consider the map $\langle \,\,,\,\,\rangle : M \times M^* \rightarrow  R$ given by $\langle x,g \rangle := g(x)$.

> *Definition*: An $R$-module isomorphism $\Phi: M \rightarrow M^* $ is said to be a canonical isomorphism if the following holds: for all $m,m'\in M$, and for all $R$-module isomorphisms $f:M\rightarrow M$, we have
> $$\langle m, \Phi(m')\rangle = \langle f(m), \Phi(f(m'))\rangle.$$

**Question:** Why the canonical isomorphism between $M$ and $M^*$ is defined in the above manner, in which we take help of the map $\langle \,\,,\,\,\rangle : M\times M^* \rightarrow R$?
(The map $\langle \,\,,\,\,\rangle$ may not come to ones mind if we ask question of natural isomorphism of $M$ and $M^*$ with only the above definition of $M^*$ and nothing more.)